# Does it make sense to make a composite index of 2 columns when one of the columns has a boolean datatype?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have 2 columns, one is a foreign key column and the other one a boolean column. Both are used in a WHERE clause. (`WHERE foreignId = ? AND approved = TRUE;`).

I know that indexes for columns that don't have allot of variety in possible values it can hold (like boolean or enum with only a few choices) do not help speed up the query. But what if you include such a column/field in a composite index together with the aforementioned foreignkey column? Would the resulting composite index be unique enough? Or would i be better of just creating an index for the foreignkey column only?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the approximate number of rows that we're talking about.  100,. 100 thousand, 100 million, 100 billion?  You would save index space just including the foreign key column.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc but would a composite index of both `foreignKeyId` and `approved` be even faster then a single index for foreignKey?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  At most, with an index on the foreign key, you will retrieve 2 rows.  You will not be able to discern the difference in speed.

Comment: What do you mean with retrieve only 2 rows? Many child rows can share the same foreign key id. And many child rows can have either true of false on the Approved field. @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - Perhaps you meant "2 columns"?  Even so, your comment does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

Long answer:

A single-column index on a low-cardinality column (boolean / enum / etc) is rarely useful.  But a multi-column index including such is likely to be useful, sometimes very effective.

The cardinality (selectivity) of each column in a multi-column index does not matter.  And it does not matter which order you put them in the index.

One example being very effective:

```
WHERE foreignId = ? AND approved = TRUE
ORDER BY foo
LIMIT 10
```

together with

```
INDEX(foreignId, approved,  -- in either order
      foo)
```

In that case, it can do all the filtering, then move onto the `ORDER BY` and avoid sorting.  But more importantly, it can stop after 10 rows.  Without that index, it would collect possibly thousands of rows, sort them, and then peel off 10.

Foreign keys...  Make sure you have a composite key, whether or not you have the FK.  A single-column FK *should* notice if you have a composite index *starting* with that column and not create an extra index.

More discussion in my blog:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql